# How to add objectId to array in Parse Core Data Browser

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to create an array of objects within the Parse Data Browser, in my web browser. I was wondering how I would go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/master/src/arrayContainsObject.js   more info for js sdk  https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/master/src/ParseObject.js#L711

Answer (score 0):

Looks like each Pointer is just a dictionary structure so the following works:

```
[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"yourClassName","objectId":"yourObjectsId"},
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"yourClassName","objectId":"your2ndObjectsId"}]
```

Comment: Careful if manually entering data! I just got a series of errors because when I typed these structures I used Left/Right Double Quotation Marks (“/”) instead of [Neutral] Quotation Marks (""). Resulting in the error: "Class name can't be 'nil':" :-)